# How do you name your methods in Repository?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

What is the best naming convention for methods in repository class (data access layer) for 
methods which returns collection of data for user's specific use case?

For example I have a `CartRepository` class with methods `GetById()`, `GeyByOrderNumber()` 
and now I need write a method which returns some data for my admin grid view - it contains for ex. filters on orderNumber and status fields.

Is this below method signature ok, or maybe `GetFilteredData()` would be better ?

Is this general rule `GetFor[Use_Case]` for that kinds of methods useful ?

```
IEnumerable<Cart> GetForAdminGridView(string orderNmuber, int status, bool showOnlyInactive)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there's not a real convention on this topic aside from a key remark: don't refer to UI elements in your repository. What if you decide to use something different than a `GridView` later on?

Go with a more general description like `GetFilteredData()` or something similar (`Filter()`, `Search()`, etc).

Comment: Yes, I agree that refering to UI isn't a good solution.

But maybe naming methods with using of word "For" (see analogy to "By") ex. `GetDataForRaportSummary()`, `GetDataForSummary()` is good solution, because they show purpose of that method. What you think ?

Comment: You should indicate what the data is about, not what it will be used for. `GetUserData()` is more appropriate for a summary about a user's data.